# Import Flat-Ui in Meteor app

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, meteor, less, flatui

I'm trying to include the [flat-ui](https://github.com/designmodo/Flat-UI) theme for bootstrap in Meteor. I have added the mrt:bootstrap-3 and less packages. Then I have copied the folders fonts, img, js and less from the flat-ui project inside lib/Flay-UI-2.2.2/ in my project directory. However I have the following compiling error:

```
While building the application:
lib/Flat-UI-2.2.2/less/modules/button-groups.less:12:35: Less compiler
error: variable @brand-primary is undefined
lib/Flat-UI-2.2.2/less/modules/buttons.less:10:14: Less compiler error:
variable @btn-font-size-base is undefined
...
```

It looks like it is not compiling in the right order, how can I solve this issue? I have also tried to rename `flat-ui.less` with `flat-ui.import.less` without any success.

**Update 1**
Following the indication of @user3435693 I was able to compile. However I still have some troubles. I'm not able to use the checkbox and switches. For example, I see switches like this

[image: meteor]

instead of this

[image: original]

Plus I'm not able to see the glyphicons. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I've figured out how it works:

1. Put the `less` folder inside the `client` folder.
2. Change the file extension of all the files from `.less` to `.import.less` as well as all the import as @user3435693 said.
3. Add `mizzao:bootstrap-3`.
4. Put the `img` and `fonts` folders in the `public` folder.
5. Attach the jQuery scripts to the template with

   ```
   Template.myTemp.rendered = function() {
     $.getScript('your/path/to/lib/application.js');
     $.getScript('your/path/to/lib/flat-ui.min.js');
   };
   ```

Then it works!

Answer (score 1):

I think it doesn't suffice if you rename `flat-ui.less` to `flat-ui.import.less`.

If you prefer to use the files from the [Flat UI repo](https://github.com/designmodo/Flat-UI/tree/master/less) instead of a package, I would proceed as follows:

1. Rename every file within the `<flat_ui_directory>` in your client code to include the `.import` keyword.
2. Rename every import that is made in `flat-ui.import.less` to include the `.import` keyword
3. Import `flat-ui.import.less` to your own less file, e.g. `style.less`

Hope that works.

Comment: This works if I move all the files to client/Flat-UI-2.2.2/ from lib/Flat-UI-2.2.2/. However I still have problems. Please see the update.